# How to call javascript and vbscript function on the same onclick= event?

Tags: javascript, function, vbscript, onclick, call

```
  onclick='showthread(); myjsfunction()' language='vbscript'>
```

somewhat to the effect of the above but does not work. Where showthread is a vbscript function and myjsfunction is a javascript function.

Thank you.

Comment: Client-side VBScript? In 2012? Why?

Comment: This will not work. You've just mixed server and client-side code. Resolve the issue differently. Tell us what you really want to do

Comment: Try updating your `onclick` to call a single JS function, and from that function call your VB function. That's how I remembered it working the last time I did this, which was a _long_ time ago, but also I just tried it and it worked (in IE8). @polin - OP has already said what is required. This is all client-side.

Comment: @polin: VBScript can be used client-side in IE-based engines.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well I didn't know that. Eager to know. Can you give any example or reference link. This would be very helpful

Comment: @polin: A brief search for "VBScript client msdn" gave me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260861(v=vs.60).aspx Take-away quote from the page: *"**Client script**. If you want to use VBScript in browser scripts, the browser must be a version of Internet Explorer. Other popular browsers might not support VBScript."* "Might not" is weasel language for "do not." IE (and browsers that are really IE in disguise) is the only major browser that supports VBScript. VBScript in the browser is effectively dead, has been for 11-12 years.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your best bet is to abandon `onxyz` handlers and hook things up properly via the DOM — or a combination of the two.

For instance, your element could hook up the VBScript via `onxyz` *(I've copied your syntax for that)*:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="showthread();" language="vbscript">
```

...and a `<script>` tag in the document could hook up the JavaScript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("mydiv").attachEvent("onclick", myjsfunction);
</script>
```

*(I'm using `attachEvent` there because I know you're using an IE-based engine, if you're using VBScript.)*

Or of course, have two `<script>` elements (one JavaScript and one VBScript) and hook up both functions via the DOM:

```
<div id="mydiv">

<script>
document.getElementById("mydiv").attachEvent("onclick", myjsfunction);
</script>

<script type="application/x-vbscript">
document.getElementById("mydiv").attachEvent "onclick", showthread
</script>
```

(Or whatever the correct MIME type is for VBScript. Or you can probably use `language="VBScript"` with an IE-based engine.)

Comment: how do I attach the event to table row? Because that's where the onclick event is sitting <tr onclick="showthread()...

Comment: @like-a-trainee: Using any of the various DOM methods to identify the table row -- `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, the `rows` property... Or, of course, since the `click` event bubbles, just hook it on the `table` or `tbody` element and refer to `event.target`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with VBScript but it seems to me that you could do something like

```
function myjsfunction() {
    window.location = "vbscript:showthread();"

    // other JS code
}
```

to call the VBScript function from JS. This is certainly hacky but I don't know of any better way.

If it's possible, though, it's probably best to convert to JavaScript entirely.

Comment: do we have to do window.location? Can't we keep it in the same window?